# React Native Drawer - Cannot read Property "isConfigured" of undefined & [Reanimated] Failed to create a worklet

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation-drawer

My Codes:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 */
import React from 'react';
import { createDrawerNavigator} from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import StockRoom from './StockRoom';
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function Refill(navigation: any): React.JSX.Element {
  interface CustomAlertProps {
    show: boolean;
    onClose: () => void;
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
      <Drawer.Navigator>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={StockRoom} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    
  );
}


export default Refill;
```

First Error:
[image]

Second Error:
[image]

I need to create a simple drawer but i can't.
How can i solve this two problem?
I tried npm uninstall and download all packages again but doesn't work.

Comment: Facing the exact same issue with react native navigation Drawer.Navigator. were you able to find the probably cause for it, or were you able to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Add this inside the your `babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:@react-native/babel-preset'],
  plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin']
};
```

After reconfiguring babel:

```
yarn start --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue to this using React Navigation Stack Navigator. It went away for me by deleting `node_modules`, clearing npm and gradle build caches, reinstalling dependencies.  Also, I had to add `react-native-reanimated` to my project dependencies.  After doing this, things were working smooth as butter for me.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of reanimated is not working properly with the drawer
try to install this version of reaminated
npm i react-native-reanimated@2.2.0

Comment: react-native-reanimated@2.2.0 won't work with latest version of react native

Answer (score 0):

Running a version of react-native-reanimated after 3.4.1, should have this issue fixed. Here is the change: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/pull/4832

I had the same issue with reanimated 3.7.0 and fixed it by installing the necessary dependencies for react-native-reanimated/plugin listed here: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/blob/main/plugin/README-dev.md

I also had to clean my project, do a brand new installation @react-navigation/drawer (including reanimated and react-native-gesture-handler) and rebuild the project. Hope this helps!